# Windows enterprise sideloading domain group policy

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-server-2008, windows-store-apps, sideloading

I'd like to sideload my Windows Store App to a Windows 8 Enterprise PC. The PC is domain-joined but now I am a little bit stuck.

As it says in the [Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852635.aspx), the Group Policy on the domain controller must be set:

> You must join the device running Windows 8 Enterprise or Windows Server 2012 to an Active Directory domain that has the Allow all trusted applications to install Group Policy setting enabled.

How do I set this Group Policy on my Windows Server 2008? There is no such policy. Does this mean that I need the newest Windows Server 2012 for this? I did set this group policy on the client as well, but anyway I need to activate a developer account. I don't want to do this because a developer account expires after 1 month...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, apparently you can add Windows 8 group policies to a Windows Server 2008.
[Administrative Templates (.admx) for Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36991)

If you dowloaded and installed this file you then can take the needed files and copy them to %systemroot%\PolicyDefinitions. Then you can activate the policy. I did this, but I still had to activate my MS developer account on the Windows 8 Enterprise machine. I don't know how to avoid this.

Comment: Hi you got any solution for bypass MS Developer account? If you got solution then please share